# Display Meta Data with HTML?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

Is it possible to display the custom field/meta data content with some html?

Usually i would use the following to just display the content...

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb__description',true);?>
```

However, when there is actually meta content i want it to appear within some html, but i only want that html to appear when there is meta data to appear?

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,<div class="box">. '_cmb__description'. </div>,true);?>
```

Is this possible? I'm not that up to scratch with it all, so wasn't sure if it was doable at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just check if you got something back from the post meta:

```
$value = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb__description',true);

if ( $value )
    echo "<div class='box'>$value</div>";
```